# can't start tomcat on vps - java VM error "could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Tags: ssh, centos, tomcat6

I can't start tomcat6 on my VPS (which has 256 MB, 512 MB burst and uses currently only 20MB of it). the log entry shows:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

i read that i can set the min and max heapsizes for the java with the -Xms and -Xmx
what do i need to do that tomcat will pass these parameters to java when trying to start the service?

Comment: ps -ef | grep tomcat should tell you if it's up, otherwise have a look in the /usr/share/tomcat6/logs files for anything obvious.

Comment: thank you. `[root@mabulous bin]# ps -ef | grep tomcat
root     13739 32480  0 17:44 pts/1    00:00:00 grep tomcat
` does that mean it's running?

Comment: you was right - there was an error, the java VM doesn't want to start - see my edited problem description

Comment: Mat, I think your question is now well-defined enough to be used in a Google search. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit /etc/default/tomcat6 and add in -Xms and -Xmx values to java opts there.

eg:-
    JAVA_OPTS=" -Xmx256m"

Comment: perfect - thanks. the actual path was `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf`